# Increase memory_limit of subdomains in the plesk panel

Tags: drupal-6, subdomain, plesk

I increased memory_limit to 512M in the plesk panel, then i ran phpinfo() and tested this two addresses:

fanap.ir/phpinfo.php ----> memory_limit=512M

test.fanap.ir/phpinfo.php ----> memory_limit=128M

How can i increase memory_limit of subdomains?

Answer (score 1):

As I know in Plesk 11 subdomains have own PHP settings.
Just click on subdomain name on sites list in "Websites & Domains" tab and there you will see "PHP settings" tab for subdomain.